# Среда программирования для С

Tags: c, ide

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую использовать среду (программу) для начала изучения языка программирования С.

Comment: @RocketGTR Смотрите похожий вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/3592/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала изучения языка C среда совсем не нужна. Среда нужна для реальных дел, а для изучения хватит любого продвинутого текстового редактора и компилятора.

Но если Вам не пугает то, что Вам придётся скачать кучу возможностей, которые Вам не скоро понадобятся, то берите самое популярное под виндой — [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).